# having trouble with rsyslog forward and include origin IP or iptables mirror while using ufw

Tags: iptables, rsyslog

How do i get `rsyslog` to mirror traffic unmodified (**including origin IP**) to another port?

I have many devices sending data into port `514` but i need two different applications on the server to receive that data.

I tried adding the following to the bottom of `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
*.* @@127.0.0.1:1514

# also tried
*.* @127.0.0.1:1514
```

The application listening on `1514` get's all the data but the source address is always `127.0.0.1`. If i send logs directly to port `1514` the application listening at `1514` see's the correct source address but now `rsyslog` doesn't see the data since it's listening on port `514`.

How do i get `rsyslog` to mirror traffic unmodified (**including origin IP**) to another port?

For whatever reason the following `iptables` rules as an alternative to the above are not redirecting traffic on Ubuntu server 18.04LTS to resolve the problem so i was hoping there was a way to tweak my `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to make sure `1514` saw the original source instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Example alternative iptables rule that isn't mirroring traffic (or at least graylog can't see it).

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 514 -j TEE --gateway 127.0.0.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.2 -p tcp --dport 514 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:1514

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 514 -j TEE --gateway 127.0.0.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.2 -p udp --dport 514 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:1514
```

Note that my `ufw` rules are `22 ALLOW Anywhere` and `514 ALLOW Anywhere`

Comment: *. * ....do you have a space between the dot and the 2nd asterisk?

Comment: no. i'll add it and see what happens and update.

Comment: no, using  `*. *` (astrix dot space astrix) throws error and stops rsyslog service  `error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.conf, on or before line 61: warnings occured in file '/etc/rsyslog.conf' around line 61 [ invalid character in selector line - ';template' expected [v8.32.0]`

Comment: Yes, sorry - it shoudnt be there, I thought I saw one. I'm not sure if ufw would need to have port 1514 ALLOWED, but your config looks good... are you sure IPTABLES isnt filtering too?